# SSRS Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I would like to know in order to use the Report Builder at the user system, What kind of licencing model we require, If we have one SSRS server (SQL Server licence) and all the users can download report builder? 
What is the licencing model to use the Report Builder? It is SQL 2008

Answer (score 2):

When you install Report Builder you should see the licensing terms.  They stated that you are free to use this product in conjunction with validly licensed SQL Server.  Look for the words: "You may not use this supplement if you do not have a license for the software."

Basically, if you or the user that is going to use this is licensed for SQL Server, then you can use this.

Sql Server Developer Edition is very very cheap per seat (approximately $50 US).  When I've run into scenarios where there is some user or analyst who doesn't need access to anything in the world but a development SQL Server, I get a copy of that license.

Comment: FYI: As noted on the SQL Server Developer Edition product page (http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/developer.aspx) the developer edition is for "development, test, and demo use" only and cannot be used in a production capacity by users or analysts.